# which is the best way to submit a form in php

Tags: php, json

I want to send the form data to server-side. I have two ways:

1. Normal form submission. 
           or
2. Convert the form data to json and send to server and decode the json at server-side.

I want to know which is the best way? Is the 2nd approach is better/secure than the 1st one? if it is than why?

Comment: Why not just the first way, no extra work needed?

Comment: Second way is not more secure, only more work..

Comment: i have done in first way but my TL is suggesting second way. Please give me best reason so that i can tell him.

Comment: Perhaps she wants you to learn a new technique so you can use it elsewhere? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods are equally secure, because they really are doing the same thing.

Things is , the normal form submit is **mandatory**. User require that functionality always. If you add the XHR `POST` to the mix, it is more of an interface feature/improvement then anything else. Under the hood it will be doing exactly the same interaction with server. The difference will be in data that you receive from server (whole page of just JSON with status details).

If you are looking for better login security, then you should focus more on HTTPS stuff, or maybe try to integrate external authentication systems, like OpenID.

Answer (score 0):

Use normal submission wen you need the user feedback, wen the page change (navigation) and wen you don't need any fancy.

And use Ajax wen you have automated data that is not direct user input and you don't want to reload the whole page.

Normal forms are pure html, and  will always work (are hard to break), also are easy to write. Ajax can break for different reasons and need much more work.

The only problem with normal forms is user using the "back" button, and having the browser shows a error message about "re-sending forms". But that can be fixed with special tecniques.

Comment: You can provide user feedback with Ajax. Your point about automated data stands for any way you submit a form, not just Ajax. Ajax isn't going to break for any more reasons than a regular form, assuming that they have javascript enabled.

Comment: Ajax is programming, and programming can have bugs.Or can be affected by changes in the rules, like same-domain. Is more "safe" to use a simple <form>.

Comment: Same-domain affects both Ajax and normal form posts. I'm not saying you're wrong that programming can have bugs, but it's 4-5 lines of code in jQuery, so chances are very slim that it will break more. Sure, it can go wrong, but so can writing an HTML form. Look how many people try to use a button input with an onclick submit, instead of a submit input.

Comment: The general rule on the web is to use the lower protocol/standard. 

@Jordan
If you want a page to reload after 2 seconds. You can do it with HTTP, or HTML or Javascript, or even have a input type="image" with a gif asking the user to reload the page.  If you can do it with http, you must do it with http, if you can do it with html, you do it in html,  and html better than javascript.

The web change faster than we think, and is device independent, we don't know what will happends 5 years down the road. Maybe everyone will start browsing the web using audio devices, withouth a graphic renderer

Comment: So what's your point exactly? If Javascript and Ajax are going to change 5 years down the road, so are HTML and other auxiliary languages. I disagree with the premise that Javascript is going to break any more than the HTML form, or especially the PHP code on the back end to support the form submission. Also, there is no general rule on the web. You do what you need to, with the technologies that are available, to support your business. There are myriad ways of implementing a function, irrespective of any levels of protocol.

Comment: Code like <form action="midata.php"><input type="text" name="data"><input type='submit'></form> depends on features from HTML 1.0 that have not changed in a long time and can survive to almost any of the terrible things that happend in a browser.  If you load a 200KB JS file from a CDN, and you must execute these 200KB of JS, that has ben written maybe 8 years ago, with asumptions about browsers of 8 years ago,  a lot of things can break. Even if you own code (not the library) is only 4 lines long.  Trust me here!, I am time traveler!

Comment: You're partially correct. If you think that writing with the future in mind will protect you for more than a few years down the road, you're in for a world of hurt. Speaking of standards, the JavaScript standard is almost as old as the HTML standard, so again, where is your proof? You say "a lot of things can break", but if anything Javascript is even MORE standardized and explicit than HTML ever has been.

Comment: Programming code stops execution after the first syntax error. But markup continue after a syntax error, and often try to make sense of the code, even if the code is malformed. As a result, tiny dependeency changes break programmng, and markup survive to even disasterous malforming and errors.

200KB of javascript (JQuery) can break in million ways down the road, while simple HTML 1.0 code will probably still work two million years down the road by aliens in a bycicle made of nanites.